# Should the if((int val = getvalue()) == x) form work

Tags: c++

This form does not compile with my VS2008 compiler.  Should it be possible?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int getvalue() { return 3; }

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
if((int val = getvalue()) == 3)
    cout << "val=" << val << "\n";
return 0;
}
```

This form does work.
    ...

```
int val;
if((val = getvalue()) == 3)

...
```

Why does it not work?

Comment: Because that is how the language was designed. You should read [The Design and Evoluation of C++](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/dne.html) which goes into why things are the way they are. But as far as I can remember it doesn't say anything about that particular thing.

Comment: that wont work and is useless, just think about the scope of val...

Comment: @pivotnig: I don't think it is useless - the very same thing is legal and very useful for loops.

Comment: Declaring local variable works only in for loop. It would be useful somewhere else too, but it doesn't work, according to standard.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7541123/defining-variables-in-control-structures

Comment: Curiously, in the Go language you can define vars in if conditions. `if v := math.Pow(x, n); v < lim { <v is visible here> ...` is legal in Go.

Comment: @Yossarian: `if (type variable = expression)` is perfectly valid C++, the most prominent example being `if (Derived* derived = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(base))`. The `if` block is entered provided the value of the variable is not "falsy" (zero, null pointer etc.)

Comment: @FredOverflow Yes, but this is arguably a misfeature; it is, at any rate, only usable in very restricted cases (e.g. where the declared data type is convertible to `bool`).  In his case, the simple answer is to just declare (and initialize) the variable before the `if`, and be done with it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not legal because you can't use a statement as an expression.

So, it's not the declaring a variable inside an `if` that's illegal, but the comparison.

Just like:

```
(int x = 3) == 3;
```

is illegal, whereas

```
int x = 3;
x == 3;
```

isn't.

Comment: If you declare a variable in an `if`, what is its lifetime? The `then` clause? The `else`clause as well? The enclosing scope?

Comment: @MikeDeSimone: read the standard - "A name introduced by a declaration in a condition (either introduced by the type-specifier-seq or the declara-
tor of the condition) is in scope from its point of declaration until the end of the substatements controlled
by the condition. ..."

Comment: @MikeDeSimone both. It's life is inside the `if` and its branches.

Comment: Not everyone who comes to SO has a personal copy of the standard, and it is not freely available online.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone I agree. There are free drafts available. Here's one - www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf

Comment: @MikeDeSimone: since you requested a quote in your other comment, I assumed you had something to check against...

Comment: Nope, I was asking because you had it and I didn't. I try to do my best here sans standard. It's a fool's errand, I know, even though language standards matter little in the real world compared to whatever syntax your compiler implements. For example, C++11 is full of stuff that is both beautiful and utterly useless since it's not implemented. Worse yet, if you use it, other programmers can't read it, and if they don't have the money to drop on a copy of the standard, they're pretty much hosed. Paid standards are a vestige of the cathedral model, and I'm not a big fan.

Comment: Also, draft versions of released standards aren't that useful since, without an updated change list, you cannot trust them.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to litter in your scope, you can use а `{}` block:

```
...
{
  int val;
  if((val = getvalue()) == 3) { 
  ... 
  }
}
...
```

`val` will be destroyed at the last `}` and won't be visible afterwards.